# cannot import electron in react componment for ipcRenderer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, electron

So I am trying to import the ipcRenderer into a react component to communicate with the electron side. The issue is I cannot import electron. I tried

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron/renderer'
```

returns module electron/renderer not found

```
import { ipcRenderer } from 'electron'
```

returns fs.existsSync is not a function

```
const renderer = require('electron');
```

returns fs.existsSync is not a function

```
const renderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
```

returns fs.existsSync is not a function

```
const renderer = window.require('electron');
```

returns window.require is not a function

I do not know what to do anymore, I have tried everything

Comment: The same to me! I feel you bro, hope someone replies with the right answer!

Answer (score 0):

I got it! using **[electron-react-bolierplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)** they prepared a custom **preload.js** script that exposes three functions to the rendered components: **myPing**: (Just a demo, send a ping message to the console) and exposes the **on** and **once** ipcRenderer methods

```
import { Component } from 'react';
...
...
    class Hello extends Component {
      componentDidMount() {
        console.log('Mounted!', 'Window', window, 'electronApi', window.electron, 'ipcRenderer', window.electron.ipcRenderer);
    
        window.electron.ipcRenderer.on('ipc-example', (arg) => {
          // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
          console.log(arg);
        });
    
        window.electron.ipcRenderer.myPing();
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
    ...
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have same problem. You should not import electron directly inside your renderer/react component. Instead in your preload.ts file you are given some basic configuration by electron-react-bolierplate to use.

So inside your react component you should use `window.electron.ipcRenderer.on('channel-name', args)` sample below

```js
  const myEventHandler = () => {
    window.electron.ipcRenderer.on('channel-name', (event, data) => {
      console.log('data, event', data, event);
    });
  };
```

window.electron, here electron is the name given in preload.ts file. `contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {...})`